# Multiple User Models with different fields and login pages?

Tags: python, django

I already have a model called **User** which looks like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
    )


    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

This **User** model has the following login page on the website:

*example.com/login/*

Now I want to create another model called **Employee**

The **Employee** model basically looks like the **User** model with some additional fields like *company*, *salary* etc.

The **Employee** user can only login on a specific page and not on the same page like the **User** model:

*example.com/employee-login/*

My question is how should I build the **Employee** model.

Is it good to create a complete separate model for the **Employee** that has nothing to do with the **User** model?

And can I use still use the Login, Register, Password Reset etc. views from from Django that I used for the **User** model?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking to use inheritance for this case? Then you could inherit the fields from the `User` superclass in an `Employee` subclass. URL routing can be managed in the usual way in `urls.py`.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Thanks, inheritance is a good idea. Do you know if I can still use the Views from Django for Login, Register, Password Reset etc. or do I have to write custom views for the Employees to get this functionality?

Comment: And there is one more problem. If someone registers as an Employee and after 2 months he wants to register as a normal user, it doesn't work because the email is already taken by the Employee account and I want to separate the accounts.